# matlab. vectorization within if/else if/else statements

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vectorization

I need some help with the following code:

```
if x(:,3)>x(:,4)
output=[x(:,1)-x(:,2)];
elseif x(:,3)<x(:,4)
output=[x(:,2)-x(:,1)];
else
output=NaN
end
```

Here is a sample data:

```
matrix x              output
10   5   1   2        -5
10   5   2   1         5     
NaN  1   1   3         NaN
```

I'm not sure how to make the code work. It just takes the first argument and ignores the else if and else arguments. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: be sure to check the `if` statement: `if ... elseif ... else ... end` (with no space between `else` and `if`)

Comment: I changed it, but didnt fix the problem

Comment: Note that your output will also be `NaN` if the last 2 columns are equal to eachother. If this is undesirable use `>=` instead of `>` OR add another index for this possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if x(:,3)>x(:,4)` doesn't really work, `if` expects either `true` or `false` not a vector. So it only evaluates the first element of the vector `x(:,3)>x(:,4)` which is why it appears to ignore your `elseif`.

So you must either use a loop or even better you can use logical indexing like this:

```
x= [10   5   1   2        
10   5   2   1        
NaN  1   1   3]

output = NaN(size(x,1),1)
I = x(:,3)>x(:,4);
output(I) = x(I,1)-x(I,2);
I = x(:,3)<x(:,4);
output(I) = x(I,2)-x(I,1)
```

Comment: Guess this is a pretty strong confirmation of my thoughts!

Answer (score 5):

Using `sign` to avoid indexing for different conditions.

```
B=diff(x,1,2);
B(B(:,3)==0,3) = NaN;
output = B(:,1) .* sign(B(:,3));
```

Or in a shorter and less readable form:

```
B=diff(x,1,2);
output = B(:,1) .* (sign(B(:,3))+0./sign(B(:,3)));
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. I wish I can all together avoid indexing for all my projects:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:

```
output = NaN(size(x,1),1);

idx1 = x(:,3)>x(:,4);
idx2 = x(:,3)<x(:,4);

output(idx1) = x(idx1,1)-x(idx1,2);
output(idx2) = x(idx2,2)-x(idx2,1);
```